Pass cookies to expo-web-browser
I'm using expo-web-browser to open webviews in my Expo app. For basic, public links this has worked great so far, using WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(url).
However, I also need to open links which require a jwt token. In my current organization, such cases are handled by passing a cookie with the jwt token in it. So, in my case I would need to pass this custom cookie along to the expo-web-browser.
I've read the documentation which states that:
"As of iOS 11, SFSafariViewController no longer shares cookies with Safari, so if you are using WebBrowser for authentication you will want to use WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync"
But, as far as I understand that method is intended to be used to login in the webview and get back some kind of auth token using the redirectUrl.
So, my question is: Is it possible at all to pass along cookies to the native Safari browser using expo-web-browser, or is it impossible because of Apple's security measures? In that case I guess I'd be forced to create some custom webview using react-native-webview or similar...
Thanks in advance!

did you figure this out?

@Simon Unfortunately not... I talked with an iOS developer in my company, and he said it was not possible in pure iOS development. So I guess expo-web-browser is based on that iOS-API that doesn't allow cookies. Not sure though...
I ended up proceeding with react-native-webview as stated above. Not as pretty, but it did the job.
